# Inserting data into MySQL from a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

An API I am querying returns the following data which I've used json_decode to put into an array.  I need to extract certain values for inserting into a MySQL database.  In the example below (which only has one ID), I want to insert ID = 4229850 and 2011 (the value of the field Vanguard).  I'm can't figure out how to navigate through the array and generate the appropriate insert statement.

```
Array 
    ( 
    [Contacts] => Array 
        ( 
        [0] => Array 
            ( 
            [Id] => 4229850 [Url] => https://abc.com 
            [FirstName] => Mol 
            [LastName] => Thompson 
            [FieldValues] => Array 
                (
                [0] => Array 
                    (
                    [FieldName] => Profile last updated [Value] => 
                    ) 
                [1] => Array 
                    (
                    [FieldName] => First name [Value] => Mol 
                    [CustomAccessLevel] => Public
                    )
                [2] => Array 
                    (
                    [FieldName] => Last name [Value] => Thompson 
                    )
                [3] => Array 
                    (
                    [FieldName] => e-Mail [Value] => abc@yahoo.ca
                    )
                [4] => Array 
                    (
                    [FieldName] => Vanguard [Value] => 2011
                    ) 
                )
            )
        ) 
    )
```

Comment: you want to retrieve above mentioned value and insert it to database?

Comment: These are two separate questions. Using MySQL with PHP is [well documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php), as are [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (Example #6).

Answer (score 2):

```
$field1=$yourArray['contacts'][0]['Id'] //Value 4229850
$field2=$yourArray['contacts'][0]['FieldValues'][4]['Value'] //Value 2011
```

Using PDO Methods

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO yourTable (field1,field2) VALUES (:field1,:field2)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':field1'=>$field1,
                  ':field2'=>$field2));
```

Using mysql_query function

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO yourTable (field1,field2) VALUES ('$field1','$field2')");
```