# MySQL | Dynamic query - online users

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm looking for the way to build dynamic query and return online users.
Please check my code below. I can't find where is mistake?
Return's me: Unknown column 'is_online' in 'where clause'...

```
    if (isset($options['online']) && $options['online'] == 1) {
       $where[]  = ' AND is_online = 1';
    } 

    $sql = ' SELECT 
       u1.*,
       u2.*,
       COUNT(s.userid) AS is_online
    FROM `#__users`     
    AS 
        u1 
    LEFT JOIN 
        `#__ds_users`   
    AS 
        u2 
    ON 
        u1.id       = u2.id 
    LEFT JOIN 
        `#__session`    
    AS 
        s 
    ON 
        u1.id       = s.userid  
    WHERE 
        1=1
    '.implode('', $where).'
    GROUP BY 
    u1.id';
```

Comment: you might want to checkout my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726512/how-to-insert-dynamic-multidimensional-array-in-database-with-mysqli

Comment: I'm guessing you can't use an alias in the WHERE condition, you should be able to use `COUNT(s.userid) = 1` there, or wrap the whole thing in a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change that portion of the clause to a `having` clause:

```
having is_online = 1
```

This variable uses an aggregation function, so you cannot put the value in the `where` clause.  However, you could instead have:

```
where s.userid is not null
```

Or, more simply, eliminate the condition and change the `left join` to `inner join`.